# How to serve my own iOS ipa (ipad install) file?

Tags: php, ios, ipad, ipa

Does anyone know how to serve my own files like TestFlight or Diawi  ?

I used Firefox web developer tools to let me pick up the header information (from Diawi) then used PHP to set header and readfile to output but this has failed - I have also tried to just reference the file via my web browser but each time my iPad Safari tells me it cannot download this file.

Comment: please explain or code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to download .ipa file directly, you should create manifest.plist file that contains app information and create a link to this .plist file like below.
Than go to this link via safari.

Manifest file should like this : https://gist.github.com/hramos/774468
And you link should like this: `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&
    url=http://example.com/manifest.plist`

You can check this page:
[Wireless AdHoc Distribution](http://gknops.github.io/adHocGenerate/)

Answer (score 0):

There are online tools that simplify this process of sharing, for example https://abbashare.com or https://diawi.com
Create an ipa file from xcode with adhoc or inhouse profile, and upload this file on these site.
I prefer abbashare because save file on your dropbox and you can delete it whenever you want